# How safe it is for a dog to go through Johannesburg Airport customs?

Tags: airports, safety, south-africa, johannesburg

Need to ship pure breed dog from US to Johannesburg, SA. I've heard a lot about high level of luggage theft at Johannesburg airport. Does this also apply to animals being transported? If so, is there anything I can do to reduce the risk?

Comment: Is a fancy dog even still valuable if stolen without its breeding paperwork?

Comment: Read about dog theft in SA.....seems like they don't care about paperwork.

Comment: "Is it safe?" is largely a matter of opinion, related to how much risk one is prepared to take. I've edited the question to try to focus on objective information, from which you can make your own decisions about safety.

Comment: Half of the people in South Africa are terrified of dogs.

Answer (score 2):

As a vet tech, I would suggest going through a professional animal transport company, I would not check the dog and have the airline handle it. I have heard a lot of stories of dogs dying in transit or being mistreated. As for the airport it's self I don't know, but if it is a good company they should ensure safe handling of the dog.